# Reading from two serial ports simultaneously in c++

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

The operating system I am working with is Windows 7. I am needing to grab data at certain intervals from a broadband card. This car sends data to two separate COM ports. COM 3 and COM 4. Every interval I will need to query the line of info on both serial ports and write them to a file.

**How do I read from two COM ports? Do I have to use threading? Is it good practice opening both at the same time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial_com.aspx). If you open up the com port and then make a call to [WaitComEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363479%28VS.85%29.aspx) in overlapped IO you'll get a handle in the [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342%28VS.85%29.aspx) that can be used in [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You should be able to do it in a single thread with the general outline below:

```
HANDLE hSerial3;
hSerial3 = CreateFile("COM3",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
//...
WaitCommEvent(hSerial3, &dwEventMask, &ov3);
WaitCommEvent(hSerial4, &dwEventMask, &ov4);
//pack ov.hEvent into arHandler
WaitForMultipleObjects (3,arHandles,FALSE,INFINITE);
```

Heavily edited due to feedback from @JimRhodes

Comment: Are you sure about that? What handles are you going to wait on? The file handles?

Comment: @JimRhodes: I think that you can.

Comment: Yes, serial port handles are waitable.

Comment: @DeadMG: I do not believe that a file handle is put into a signaled state when data is received. You need to use WaitCommEvent.

Comment: @JimRhodes is right. Technically you can use single thread to read from both for the sake of it but in my view that's not the great way. If you write your thread properly, you can use the same thread to read from both ports and even more, you just start a separate instance of the thread for each port.

Comment: @AndréCaron: You can wait on the file handle but that won't tell you if received data is available.

Comment: @PaulRubel: WaitCommEvent will not create the event. You need to create the event yourself and put it into the OVERLAPPED structure. OVERLAPPED structure must be completely initialized before passing it to WaitCommEvent.

Comment: Yes, it was meant as the gist of an answer. You're absolutely right. The link at the top gives complete code. Note that I didn't declare dwEventMask either.

Answer (score 2):

You will read from both ports the same way that you read from one port. Since both ports are independent, there is no issue. Have one thread to read from say COM3 and another thread to read from COM4. Yes it is absolutely fine to read from both ports at the same time, nothing wrong with it. In fact you can even read from many more ports at the same time not just two.

Comment: Indeed.  Except that if you use blocking I/O, you can't block on both ports directly.  Serial ports are waitable objects, you can use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) to wait any of the two (or both) to be ready.

Comment: @Andre Been a while since I worked with this, I don't remember the specifics...: can you do that on the port HANDLEs directly or do you have to set the ports up for asynchronous I/O and wait for the handle of the event you get from the OVERLAPPED struct? As I remember it, the latter is rather cumbersome.

Comment: @Andre can you expand on this?  Why can't the two threads be blocking on their respective ports at the same time?

Comment: @Lundin: If you open the ports for overlapped I/O, you'd be much better off using I/O completion ports or something else.  It's also been a while since I used a serial port, but you should use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` on a serial port with blocking I/O if you have other handles to wait on at the same time (such as an "abort" event).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Sorry the note wasn't clear.  I meant in a single-threaded scenario.  Two ports can be used from two threads at the same time, each in their own thread.  However, you need to perform synchronization afterwards.  Unless you need the computing power of two threads (doesn't seem so), you're better off waiting for I/O on both ports in a single thread.

Comment: Still, you are going to have to WaitFor... somewhere in the main thread while it could be doing other things. Or alternatively go back and poll the handles now and then, which may not even be an option depending on data baudrate. I suppose if you set it to asynchronous IO you can have the callback function send a message to your main Window loop (again assuming GUI). Anyway, I have done plenty of COM-port apps in the past and all of them with threads. I only have good experience from that.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this site gives an example
http://www.fogma.co.uk/foggylog/archive/140.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to open each port as a file. The names to use would be "COM3:" and "COM4:". You will want to set an event mask (SetCommEvent) and create a thread to read from each port. You use WaitCommEvent in your thread and check if the event is for received data. If so you use ReadFile to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your design is to poll the ports for data queued there.  This is the simplest way to read data from these ports.  You can use one thread to poll the two ports, one after the other.

```
Open COM3
Open COM4

LOOP
Check for data on COM3.
If data, read and process
Check for data on COM4.
If data, read and process
Sleep for remainder of polling interval
repeat from LOOP
```

All this should probably be done in one thread, so that another main thread can look after user interaction, etc, while the polling thread sleeps.

Whether or not to do the data processing in this thread or in another depends ... on a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use threading when communicating with COM ports.

Otherwise your program will be yet another of those incredibly crappy amateur ones that lock up the main GUI thread completely while waiting for the COM port. Nothing screams "I'm a bad programmer" more than such programs, in my opinion.

In this particular case, using several threads sounds like a sensible choice.

Comment: Who said it was a GUI application?

Comment: @André GUI thread, main thread, whatever. The same applies, you don't want to lock up the main thread. The crappiness of programs doing that is just more evident in GUIs. In my experience WaitFor... functions don't improve this lockup notably in a single-thread app.

Comment: Threading is often the easiest answer, but it's inelegant, IMO.  If you use asynchronous IO properly there is no need to lock up the GUI while waiting for data.